# How to get files data in base64 from slack channel.?

Tags: slack, slack-api

Hello how to get files data in base64 from slack channel.

When user add the files to slack channel the response contains the URL of the files. But its possible to get content in base64 ..?

Comment: Why Base64? It's very inefficent. Every language for the web today (including JavaScript) can handle binary blob/stream objects efficienctly.

Comment: Hello Thanks for the response. I want to use that base64 to create attachments in servicenow thats the reason I want it in base64. Is it possible to get file information in base64 from slack..? Binary can also possible in servicenow but I don't know how to retrieve information in binary format